# Why this are same adresses for the samr HANDLES (CPP HANDLES.)?

Tags: c++

I did the next three examples:

```
void main()
{
    HANDLE A = ShellExecute(NULL, "open", R"(C:\Users\Gustabo\Desktop\noticed_files.txt)", "", "", SW_SHOW);
    HANDLE B = ShellExecute(NULL, "open", R"(C:\Users\Gustabo\Desktop\clientserver.txt)", "", "", SW_SHOW);
    HANDLE C = ShellExecute(NULL, "open", R"(C:\Users\Gustabo\Desktop\noticed_files.txt)", "", "", SW_SHOW);
    std::cout << A << std::endl;
    std::cout << B << std::endl;
    std::cout << C << std::endl;
    system("pause");
    ExitProcess(0);
}
```

This are three different HANDLES(simmingly).
Each HANDLE should reffer to another process (but it doesnt.).

The output:

> 0000002A
>
> 0000002A
>
> 0000002A

Why this three HANDLES dont have each one another address?

Comment: `HANDLE` is not a standard C++ datatype, and `ShellExecute()` isn't a standard C++ function.

Comment: I suspect it's not showing the whole handle, maybe because it's being implicitly converted to an inappropriate type.

Comment: `0000002A` doesn't seem like a likely address for a structure in user memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return value of [ShellExecute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx) is not an handle. It is just indication of success/failure of the function call: indeed if it is greater than 32 then the function call succeeded.